# Problem generating the heat map

Tags: plotting, color

I'm trying to generate the following heatmap (Figure 2, page 7 of [this article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1140/epjc/s10052-023-11264-w.pdf?pdf=button))
[image]

The equation I used for the heat map was ($R_{sh}$, equation 52 in the paper)

```
K[\[Omega]_, R_] := Subscript[r, ph] Sqrt[f[Subscript[r, 0]]/f[Subscript[r, ph]]];
```

where (model 1, page 3)

```
Subscript[r, ph] = ((4 \[Omega] + 1) Subscript[M, 0])/(1 - 2 \[Omega]);

f[r_] := (1 - 2 Subscript[M, 0]/r)/(1 - (2 Subscript[M, 0])/R) ((r - 2 Subscript[M, 0])/(R - 2 Subscript[M, 0]))^(4 \[Omega]);
```

So, I wrote the following line (for $M_0 = 4.1 \times 10^6$ and $r_0 = 10^{10}$)

```
DensityPlot[K[\[Omega], R], {\[Omega], 0, 1 }, {R, 2 10^15, 1 10^16},  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

However, I get the following. A suggestion or hint would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: If you change the plot range for $\omega$ to 0.125 to 1, it plots. `K[w,R]` is `ComplexInfinity` at `w=1/8`, and complex for `w<1/8`

Comment: @ydd Oh sure! You're right. Thank you very much :) but although I got the plot, I have the question why I don't get the same scale in the domain as in the article